# Why isn't Frozone's wife more concerned about him breaking the law?

Tags: the-incredibles

In *The Incredibles*, the supers are banned, and Mr. Incredible only goes out with Frozone at night, in secret, to rescue people from burning buildings and so on. It's in secret so that nobody else will know — including their wives. Yet, when Frozone asks his wife for his super suit and claims, "The city is in danger!" she acts completely unfazed that he's about to go out and do something illegal. (She only cares about her evening, but going out to do superhero things seems very normal to her.)

Why is she so apathetic about him breaking the law?

Comment: Wives always know. Always.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to answer this one. Helen Parr works out very very quickly that Bob hasn't been out bowling, that he has in fact been out saving lives because his suit has been used ("*Is this rubble?*"). 
It seems logical that Honey Best would be at least as observant about Frozone's suit and even if she's not spotted it *this particular time*, she would have noticed previous times.

Comment: Or maybe Helen spoke to her.

Comment: According to Brad Bird, she may have been a super. Her character design was used in the film as one of the background characters at the wedding, but she wasn't named *"We have used her design and she is a hero but there’s not a lot of screen time though"*

Comment: her being a super would also raise questions - why didnt she go out and help frozone save the city from the omnidroid?

Comment: @Jon - Not everyone's superpowers are useful in that sort of emergency. "*The ability to communicate with aquatic animals*" isn't going to be anything helpful here.

Comment: She has her priorities. What's a little vigilantism compared to dinner? They've been planning it for two months!

Comment: @Valorum don't be so hasty, there's always a canal https://youtu.be/y6l7Hzv4PQ4

Comment: Lo and behold, this opinion-based question has spawned an opinion-based answer. Who could have predicted such a thing :-)

Answer (score 3):

Even assuming that Frozone's wife does not actually know that he has still been engaging in unsanctioned superhero activities (a highly dubious assumption), her relative willingness to let him go out as a costumed vigilante is not so unreasonable.  People do illegal things all the time, and their families often take it in stride when they find out.*

This woman married Lucius Best knowing that he was a super who was devoted to helping people.  She presumably admired that about him, and she loves him.  Even though she apparently thinks that he is overstating the seriousness of the situation, she does respect his judgement about whether he can make a useful contribution.

*As Karen Hill states in [*Goodfellas*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099685/), about a much nastier group of criminal husbands:

> After awhile, it got to be all normal.  None of it seemed like crime.  It was more like Henry was enterprising, and that he and the guys were making a few bucks hustling, while all the other guys were sitting on their asses, waiting for handouts.  Our husbands weren't brain surgeons, they were blue-collar guys.  The only way they could make extra money, real extra money, was to go out and cut a few corners.